# Извлечение даты с помощью Regexp_extract bigquery

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bigquery

имеются строки содержащие дату в формате 01.10.2021, при этом с строке может содержаться текст.

Пробовал следующим образом

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Дата когда записали, r'^[0-9]{2}[/\.][0-9]{2}[/\-][0.9]{4}$')
```

и так же еще один вариант

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Дата когда записали, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

оба варианта возвращает `null`

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

В регулярном выражении должна быть захватывающая подмаска, иначе `REGEXP_EXTRACT` не сможет вернуть значение.

Кроме того, если дата не является строкой целиком, нельзя использовать якори `^` и `$`, так как они требуют наличия начала или конца строки соответственно.

`[0.9]` - это явная опечатка.

Используйте

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Дата когда записали, r'(?:\D|^)(\d{2}[-/.]\d{2}[-/.]\d{4})(?:\D|$)')
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vXMMZF/2).

*Подробности*

- `(?:\D|^)` - начало строки или символ, отличный от цифрового
- `(\d{2}[-/.]\d{2}[-/.]\d{4})` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: две цифры, символ `-`, `/` или `.`, две цифры, символ `-`, `/` или `.`, четыре цифры
- `(?:\D|$)` - конец строки или символ, отличный от цифрового